# In Javascript what is the method to allow integer and float but not chars

Tags: javascript, lodash

In my javascript variable I am getting the value as `"abc"` or `"123"` or `"123.456"` based on the input given in the `input` field. For all the values the type is `string` even if the entered value is number or float.

`typeof(variable)` gives `string` always.

The following method will be triggered on each `keydown`. I am also using the `lodash` library

```
convertMethod(val) {
    console.log(round(val,2).toString())    //round is a lodash method which is imported already
}
```

When I `round` the value the decimal point is not coming. I just want to round the value by two decimal points if the entered value is digits and not alphabets. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it number or not using `isNaN`. Round it up if it is a number:

```
convertMethod(val) {
    if(!isNaN(val))
       console.log(round(val,2).toString())
    else
       console.log(val)
}

convertMethod("qw")
convertMethod("12.3456")
convertMethod("12.432")
convertMethod("12")
```

Output:

```
"qw"
"12.35"
"12.43"
"12"
```

Comment: As my flow is calling the method on `keydown` when I press decimal point it won't come.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string to a number (via `_.toNumber()` or the `+` operator. Then check if it's a number using `_.isFinite()` which returns `false` for non numbers, Infinite, -Infinite, and `NaN`.

```js
const { isFinite, round } = _

const convertMethod = val => {
  if (isFinite(+val))
    console.log(round(val, 2).toString())
  else
    console.log(val)
}

convertMethod('5.4435')

convertMethod('abc')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: `isNumber('5.4567')` would result in `false` and so it won't be rounded to 2 decimals.

Comment: `IsNumber` will return false in both cases like `"123"` and `"asd"`. So we can't use this